# Flashlight error

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have a bit of a problem with the code in my flash demo application, currently I have tried the application on samsung phone and have turned it on or off.
But the flashlight is only on when the phone screen is still on, and vice versa when the phone screen goes off, the flashlight application is also turned off. While the flashlight application is still on.

This is my entire code

File manifest

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.demo.flashlight">

        <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

           


            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity> <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
            
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

File Activity_main

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    tools:context="com.demo.flashlight.MainActivity">



    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:srcCompat="@drawable/on"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

File MainActivity

```html
package com.demo.flashlight;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imageButton;
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    private Camera.Parameters params;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);


        /*
   * First check if device is supporting flashlight or not
   */
        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        // if device support camera?
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
            return;
        }
        // get the camera
        getCamera();

        // displaying button image
        toggleButtonImage();

  /*
   * Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
   */
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isFlashOn) {
                    // turn off flash
                    turnOffFlash();
                } else {
                    // turn on flash
                    turnOnFlash();
                }

          }
        });

  
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /*
//         * Get the camera
//         */
    private void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Turning On flash
     */
    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;
            toggleButtonImage();
        }

    }

    /*
     * Turning Off flash
     */
    private void turnOffFlash() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isFlashOn = false;
            toggleButtonImage();
        }
    }
    /*
     * Toggle switch button images changing image states to on / off
     */
    private void toggleButtonImage() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
        } else {
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        }
    }

    @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();

  // on pause turn off the flash
  turnOffFlash();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onRestart() {
  super.onRestart();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  // on resume turn on the flash
  if (hasFlash)
   turnOnFlash();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

  // on starting the app get the camera params
  getCamera();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();

  // on stop release the camera
  if (camera != null) {
   camera.release();
   camera = null;
  }
 }
}
```

I do not know how to fix it. Can you fix or guide me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When the screen turn off, the activity call onPause and onStop.

Try to remove `turnOffFlash();` in your onPause.

If it doesn't work, try to see your onStop.

Good Luck

Comment: I also checked and try the functions onDestroy ..... onStop the such not no change

Comment: you have remove/commented all the `turnOffFlash();` and the flash still turnoff when screen turnoff ?

Comment: Yes. I also tried removing turnOffFlash (); There are in all functions from onDestroy ..... onStop but it is still off screen so.

And when I delete all the code from onDestroy ..... onStop, the flashlight works even when the phone screen is off but an error occurred when I pressed the Pack to go back to the screen before it. Do not turn it off yourself and when you re-open the flashlight application to turn it off, it also can not turn off the flashlight.
I have to power off the phone and restart

Comment: If you have deleted your `onDestroy` and `onStop` ect, are you sure to havn't deleted the super call ? I mean that if you have deleted the complete override its good, but if you have an `override` of the `onStop` for exemple, and you havn't the `super.onStop();` in your function, it's the reason of the crash.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still struggling with my first app but have not found a way to fix this problem.
How can I fix the above error so that the flashlight in androidn can work as intended.
I tried removing or adding the code but it still does not change anything.
You or someone can help me.